# How can I get some parameter value in jquery raty plugin, with click event?

Tags: jquery, rating, raty

I am working on a project. Its looking like a blog site. In index page, i have added raty plugin for rate the article. When I rate a post, i am getting ratting value by click event. I need that article id & user id on click function of raty function. How can I get this ?

My HTML code :

```
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
         <h2 class="book-title"><%= user[i].writeArticle[j].title%></h2>
                  <h4 class="book-writer">লেখাঃ <%= user[i].name%></h4>
                  <h4 class="book-writer">ছবিঃ সংগৃহীত</h4>
         <h4 class="sub-level"><%= user[i].writeArticle[j].cetagory%></h4>
         <h4 class="sub-level"> লেভেল :<span><%= user[i].writeArticle[j].label%></h4>

          <span class="star"> </span>

    </div>
```

My Jquery code:

```
   $('.star').raty({

    click: function(score, evt) {
    var rating=score;
    console.log(rating);

    // need article title here:

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the id's as data-title-id and data-user-id attributes on the .star element. Then in the event handler you can do $(this).attr('data-title-id') to get the title id.

Edit example:

```
<span class="star" data-title-id="74">
```

Now in the click handler

```
$(this).attr('data-title-id')
```

Should return "74"

Comment: can you show me some example ? Coz I am not expert in jquery, I am new in Jquery. Please give me some link or example.